# Save Azure Pipelines Agent workspace for debugging

Tags: azure-pipelines

When you run build pipelines on e.g. Jenkins there is the capability to look at the workspace after the build has been executed. This often helps to debug build issues.

I am wondering how such a similar goal could be achieved with Azure pipelines. Or what in general is the best approach to debug build issues on a local machine?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what in general is the best approach to debug build issues on a local machine?

As far as I know, we could directly check the build message with the Build log in Azure Devops.

For example：

[image]

Generally, the error message will be included in the Build log.

You also could set the variable `system.debug = true` in Pipeline definition. Then you could get the detailed debug log.

[image: variables]

On the other hand, the azure devops agents also have the WorkSpace. You can determine the location of the workspace by checking this variable(`$(Pipeline.WorkSpace)`). The workspcace contains the source files and output files.

For [Self-Hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install), you could directly navigate to the workspace path on your local machine.

If you want to check the files in Azure Devops, you could use `Publish Build Artifacts` task to publish the workspace files to artifacts.

For example:

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(pipeline.workspace)'
    ArtifactName: drop
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Are the build artefacts kept forever or only as long as the build is kept?
How is the consumed storage for build artefacts charged?

Comment: @Marko  The artifacts will not keep forever.  You could set `Retention policy` in `Project Settings -> Settings`. And if the build is deleted , the artifacts will be deleted too.